# how to group sharepoint list fields under a label in editform and newform of a SPList?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have to group few sharepoint list fields unde a label in edit form and new form.how to group sharepoint list fields under a label in editform and newform of a SPList?

Answer (score 2):

Since no version has been specified, this is for SP 2010.

**One way**

Open the site in SharePoint Designer. Click **Lists and Libraries** in the Site Objects and select the desired list.

In the Forms section, open the NewForm.aspx or the EditForm.aspx. Hide the existing form thus: enable split view, select the web part and in the code view window find the line that says

```
<IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
```

Change it to

```
<IsVisible>false</IsVisible>
```

In Design View click below the existing web part and then click Insert Ribbon > New Item Form dropdown > Select the list. A new form web part will be added to the page. Select the new web part and click on the Options Ribbon > Add/Remove Columns.

Add the columns you want to see on the form and order them as desired. Now you can edit the table in Design view and use the Table ribbon commands to insert rows between fields to style the form.

By hiding the original form instead of deleting it, it can be recovered if the new form does not work as expected.

**Another way**

Open the site in SharePoint Designer. Click **Lists and Libraries** in the Site Objects and select the desired list.

In the Forms section, click the **New** button, enter a file name and make sure the "New item form " is selected (for an Edit form select the "Edit Item form" option) and hit OK.

Edit the new page. You will see a form web part just like the one created with the method above. Style the table and insert rows with the Table ribbon commands.

Set the new form to be the default from the List Management page in SPD: Select the form and click "Set as Default" in the Forms ribbon.

By creating a new form instead of manipulating the existing form, you can always revert to the original form as the default if something goes wrong.

**Yet another way**

If you have the Enterprise version of SharePoint 2010 you can use InfoPath to style a form as desired. Just insert rows in the InfoPath table and move fields to the desired positions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through SharePoint designer. open these pages with designer and generate the corresponding XSLT(by right clicking on the webpart and selecting the appropriate XSLT generating option). XSLT can be modified to match the required UI.

Regards
Manju